# Daydream keyboard implementation

Tags: google-vr, daydream

I am attempting to implement the Daydream keyboard into an app built in Unity and am not able to get this to work. I have added the keyboard prefab as a sibling of the main camera and added two input fields with the `onpointerclick` function added as instructed. I however get a null reference exception and assume this is due to the daydream keyboard delegate field being blank. The example scene in the SDK shows the daydream delegate example prefab but I am unsure how to implement this for two input fields. Also does the keyboard render in the Unity editor or must it be built and run on a phone?

Comment: Just to add I am using Unity 2018.1.0f2 and GVR SDK 1.3

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and has probably already been answered, but I figured I'd publicize my answer anyway.

For those reading, if you haven't checked out the *Keyboard Demo* scene that can be found within the Demos folder of the Google VR Unity package, I would highly recommend doing so. Following this object hierarchy has worked for me in the past.

To answer your ***first question***, it seems that they have included a `KeyboardDelegateExample` object within the scene's hierarchy, and then used this object as the Keyboard Delegate in the `GVRKeyboardManager`.

They manage to fake an Input Field by creating a background and overlaying a Text object on top. If this method does not suffice and using an Input Field is crucial in your particular case, then drop your Input Fields into two separate `GVRKeyboardCanvas` objects.

Clicking on either canvas will activate the GVR Keyboard. You may have to add a small script to manage the transitioning of the input field.

***Lastly***, no the GVR Keyboard does not render in the Unity Editor, it only appears while running a build. Hopefully this will be addressed in later releases. There are also Keyboard plugins that you may find useful on the Asset Store.